# How to Edit Sagemaker Labeling Shortcut Tab?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ground-truth

I'm able to change the instructions in the SageMaker GroundTruth labeling user interface as in the picture, but I can't edit the shortcuts tab. I can simply edit inside the 'full-instructions' or 'short-instructions' tags in the html template, but there is no such tag for 'shortcuts' as far I see from my online search and going through sample templates. How can I update the shortcuts to reflect the new shortcuts I added?

You can see the Instructions tab updated in the top partial screenshot, but I still don't know how to update the Shortcuts tab.

[image]

[image]